# Check for maximum amount of records in a period

Tags: mysql, sql, database, algorithm

I've got a table with a "date" column (timestamp). What I'm trying to achieve is to check if after inserting a row there will be no more than 3 records contained in a single 24 hours period, for example:

I have records with the following dates:

```
1. 2015-05-31 23:14:00
2. 2015-06-01 02:07:00
3. 2015-06-01 15:16:00
```

So now I shouldn't be able to to insert a row with the date of (for example) `2015-06-01 16:01:00` or `2015-06-01 01:01:00` but I should be able to add records with the dates of (for example): `2015-06-01 23:50:00`, `2015-05-31 01:05:00`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The 24 hour period here is very complex, since your 24 hour period can vary from the time in your new record +- 00:00:00.0000..1 to time in your new record +- 23:59:59.99999...9!

Comment: How would you want your DB system to restrict an insert on an arbitrary number of entries for a given value interval? Seems more like business logic for me.

Comment: well the place to do it is in a before insert trigger.

Comment: @inquizitive, fortunately it doesn't have to be this accurate, it could be even a few of seconds of inaccuracy.

Comment: How can I do it in my business logic? I'm not going to download 1 million records and then check conditions for each row?

Answer (score 0):

There is a little trick that you can achieve this problem with purely SQL

```
SET @DATE = '2015-05-31 1:14:00';

INSERT tbldate(inputdate)
SELECT @DATE FROM
(
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) AS c
        FROM tbldate AS t1 INNER JOIN tbldate AS t2 
        WHERE
            t1.inputdate <= t2.inputdate AND
            t2.inputdate <= t1.inputdate + INTERVAL 24 HOUR AND  
            t1.inputdate BETWEEN @DATE - INTERVAL 24 HOUR AND @DATE
        GROUP BY
            t1.inputdate
    ) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT 0 AS c)
) AS r
HAVING MAX(r.c) < 2
```

where @DATE is date you want to insert.

Comment: This is incorrect. If you have: 2015-05-10 10:00:00, 2015-05-10 12:00:00, 2015-05-10 23:00:00 and then try to insert a record with the date of: 2015-05-10 01:00:00 then it will work but there's 4 records in the same day (24 hours period)

Comment: @user294034, can you define the definition of 24 hours period? Is it 24 hours before and after the inserted date, 12 before and after inserted date, or no 3 date of the same day?

Comment: Please take a look at the first post again: "What I'm trying to achieve is to check if after inserting a row there will be no more than 3 records contained in a single 24 hours period". What I meant there is: After inserting a row no such 24 hour period exists, in which there's more than 3 records contained. I never said it is related just to the inserted row :-) No such period should exist overally. In your example and my explanation there's such period and it's from 2015-05-10 00:00:00 to 2015-05-10 24:00:00 (for example) It also could be from 2015-05-10 00:00:05 to 2015-05-11 00:05:00 etc.

Comment: There should be no @date here, so minus 1 for that. But plus 1 for generally being on the right lines

Comment: Not really, it's still incorrect. Consider the following: You have: 2015-01-10 10:00:00, 2015-01-10 11:00:00, 2015-01-11 10:00:00 and then you try to add a record with the date of 2015-01-11 11:00:00. Your conditions would work here but there's a 24 hour period, for which there's more than 3 records contained in it (2015-01-10 10:00:00 - 2015-01-11 10:00:00)

Comment: @user294034, I have updated my answer. Hopefully, it will solve your problem. I haven't tested with all the cases so I am not sure if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So, essentially, you want to prevent the insertion of dates which fall within the following ranges, if there are already two dates within those ranges:

```
SELECT x.id, x.dt - INTERVAL 24 HOUR min_range, x.dt max_range FROM my_table x
UNION
SELECT x.id, x.dt, x.dt + INTERVAL 24 HOUR max_range FROM my_table x;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | min_range           | max_range           |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2015-05-30 23:14:00 | 2015-05-31 23:14:00 |
|  2 | 2015-05-31 02:07:00 | 2015-06-01 02:07:00 |
|  3 | 2015-05-31 15:16:00 | 2015-06-01 15:16:00 |
|  1 | 2015-05-31 23:14:00 | 2015-06-01 23:14:00 |
|  2 | 2015-06-01 02:07:00 | 2015-06-02 02:07:00 |
|  3 | 2015-06-01 15:16:00 | 2015-06-02 15:16:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I'm not suggesting that this is the most efficient solution, but I think it works...

```
SET @dt = '2015-06-01 23:50:00'
INSERT INTO my_table (dt)
SELECT @dt 
  FROM (SELECT 1) m
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT a.* 
         FROM
            ( SELECT x.id, x.dt - INTERVAL 24 HOUR min_range, x.dt max_range FROM my_table x
               UNION
              SELECT x.id, x.dt, x.dt + INTERVAL 24 HOUR FROM my_table x
            ) a
         JOIN my_table b
           ON b.dt BETWEEN a.min_range AND a.max_range
        GROUP 
           BY a.id 
            , a.min_range
            , a.max_range
       HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
    ) n
   ON @dt BETWEEN n.min_range AND n.max_range
WHERE n.id IS NULL LIMIT 1;
```